# Meteor: How to sort documents by the first item of an array

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, sorting, meteor

Research papers should be sorted by the author's last name. This is how a JSON looks like with one author:

```
{
    "_id" : "ADnijjRpoWkTEGgkc",
    "authors" : [ 
        {
            "lastName" : "Rahbaran",
            "firstName" : "Amir"
        }
    ],
    "title" : "Bricolage revisted",
    "outlet" : "Journal of Strategic Management",
    "year" : "2017",
    "abstract" : "dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ..."
}
```

The corresponding Template helper works perfectly if there's only one author stored:

```
return Publications.find({}, {
      sort: {"authors.lastName": -1}
    }).fetch();
```

**The problem**: In many cases, you have multiple authors for a single research paper:

This would be the JSON:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56b06047204a563ca4207e8e"),
    "authors" : [ 
        {
            "lastName" : "Lennon",
            "firstName" : "John"
        }, 
        {
            "lastName" : "McCartney",
            "firstName" : "Paul"
        }
    ],
    "title" : "The Beatles - revisted",
    "outlet" : "Journal of Great Music",
    "year" : "1968",
    "abstract" : "Ob-La-Di, Ob-La-Da ... "
}
```

Now, I tried `sort: {"authors.lastName.0": -1}` or `sort: {"authors.lastName[0]": -1}` to no avail.

I came along concepts of map, reduce and aggregate but wouldn't know how to apply here and if it's necessary, respectively.

Or maybe Meteor has package or "trick" for that?

Any help really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you always have at least one author, you can do the following:

```
Publications.find({}, {
  sort: {
    'authors.0.lastName': -1
  }
});
```

Comment: This did the track, thx! :) Only little problem: It sorts like this: 1st: Dada Zetty AND Amir Aaron 2nd: Dada Zetty. Would be nicer if the paper with a single author would be shown first. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
db.publications.find({}).sort({"authors.lastName":-1})
```

Works perfectly fine. It sorts `authors` array within document first, picks the first element, and then sorts documents. [Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/).

Comment: It does but it sorts papers with multiple authors first, then with two authors, then with a single author

Comment: Just to clarify, it happens only for documents, which have same "biggest" author. You probably need to add this "secondary sort" requirement to the question, but I am afraid aggregation is the only way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative using the **[aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/)** through the **[`aggregate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate)** method, you can sort the authors array as well as the documents. Though **[`aggregate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate)** isn't supported yet in meteor, you need to get the aggregation framework package installed - it doesn't do anything to fancy, just wraps up some Mongo methods for you.

Just meteor add **[`meteorhacks:aggregate`](https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/aggregate)** and you should be in business. This will add proper aggregation support for Meteor.

Now you would need to run this pipeline to achieve the desired result:

```
var pipeline = [
    { "$unwind": "authors" },
    { "$sort": { "authors.lastName": -1 } },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$authors",
            "authors": { "$push": "$authors" },
            "title": { "$first": "$title" },
            "outlet": { "$first": "$outlet" },
            "year": { "$first": "$year" },
            "abstract": { "$first": "$abstract" }
        }
    },
    { "$sort": { "authors.lastName": -1 } },
];

return Publications.aggregate(pipeline);
```

Comment: looks great but too complicated for me :( maybe in a few months. is there any benefit to do it this was instead of @corvid s way?